# Every partial isometry extends

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology, metric-spaces, isometries

I am interested in metric spaces $X$ where every isometry between two subsets of the space extends to a full isometry $X \to X$. Is there a name for this kind of space? Is there some paper which studies them?

Comment: Applied to singleton this makes it homogenous under isometries. Applied to subsets of cardinal $\le 2$ this is called "2-point homogeneous". Already this is a strong condition. I guess it has a name when this holds for all finite subsets as this appears in model theory... here it's just called "homogeneous" https://www.uni-muenster.de/SFB878/publications/files/phpkARfIL1786.pdf (by MacPherson and Tent).